# Direct sum counterexample

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, examples-counterexamples, direct-sum

Let $V$ be a vector space over  a field $\mathbb{F}$, and let $W_i\  (i=1,...,4)$ be four distinct nonzero subspaces of $V$. Suppose that $W_i \cap W_j =$ {$0$} for all $i\ne\ j$. Is it true that the sum $$W_1+W_2+W_3+W_4$$ is a direct sum? Give a proof if $'yes'$ or a concrete counter example if $'no'$.

I know it is not a direct sum but I cannot provide a concrete example. Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint: Consider four distinct lines (passing through $(0,0)$) in $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: @JohnMa why take lines which passes through the origin in R^2

Comment: @Ramos the lines have to be subspace of $\mathbb R^2$, so must passes through the origin.

Comment: @JohnMa then the intersection would be {0} and hence a direct sum right?

Comment: Then $W_i \cap W_j = \{0\}$ but $W_1 + W_2 + W_3 + W_4$ is not a direct sum. @Ramos . If it's a direct sum, it has to be four dimensional.